# I need help making a program that will take random values of a dictionary and put them in another

Tags: python, dictionary

This is meant for quiz I am trying to program in python. I have no ideas on how to proceed with this part of my program, since I'm fairly new to programming, but essentially I'm trying to set the key values of dico_q_ran to the values taken randomly from q_bank.

```python
q_bank = {1 : {
        "question" : "",
        "answer" : ""
    },
    2 : {
        "question" : "",
        "answer" : ""
    },
    3 : {
        "question" : "",
        "answer" : ""}
    etc...
    25 : {
        "question" : "",
        "answer" : ""}

dico_q_ran = {0, 1 , 2, ...., 10}

for i in range(1, 11):
    key_rand = (random.randrange(0,26))
    dico_q_alea[i] = banque_de_questions[key_rand]
```

Sorry if the naming is a bit weird, I did light translation of the names from french so it would make a bit more sense for english speakers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few problems here. Firstly, `dico_q_ran` is defined as a set, not a dict, so `dico_q_alea[i]` assignment is not possible. If you want it to be a dict, just init it empty as `dico_q_ran = {}`. I'd consider using lists instead, though.

Secondly, I'd suggest using lists for both `q_bank` and `dico_q_ran`, since your keys are sequential numbers, and that's what lists are for:

```
q_bank = [
    {
        "question": "...",
        "answer": "...",
    },
}
```

That will also help you fix another problem more easily. Current randomization doesn't guarantee that the same question won't be used twice. With lists it's getting as simple as:

```
dico_q_alea = random.sample(q_bank, 10)
```